# gl3w and GL extensions

Tags: opengl, glew, glx, opengl-extensions

I am targeting GL Core Profile on Linux. When I directly use the system GL headers like so:

```
#include <GL/glcorearb.h>
```

...then everything works as expected, and I can use GL extensions too, e.g. `glPushGroupMarkerEXT()` calls.

But since I've integrated [imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui), I have been forced to go through a [GL Loader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) (I was not able to make imgui work without a loader.)
So I have followed the imgui examples, and now use [gl3w](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w).

Now that I go through gl3w, I can no longer use those GL extensions:

```
src/wld.cpp:373:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'glPushGroupMarkerEXT'
```

I looked, but gl3w does not seem to come with a separate header for extension, like glew does: the `glxew.h` file.

Does this mean that I cannot use `glPushGroupMarkerEXT()` if I use gl3w as a GL loader?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it wasn't mentioned in the README before (it is now, I created a pull rq) but there is a command line option to gl3w's generator script:

```
gl3w_gen.py --ext
```

When using the `--ext` flag, the extensions will be available in the generated `GL/glcorearb.h` header.

The gl3w packed with the imgui repository was generated without this flag, hence the extensions were not available.